# Is there a "global" kind of imports statement in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a class library called "VectorExt"

Since I use it in every .vb file in the project I'm working on, I have written "Imports VectorExt" in every single one of them. Is there a way to save me the trouble and have it imported across the project? Sorta like some of the basic .net namespaces are already available despite no imports statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [Add or Remove Imported Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w4tctcf.aspx) into your project.

> To add an imported namespace
>
> 1. In Solution Explorer, double-click the My Project node for the project.
> 2. In the Project Designer, click the References tab.
> 3. In the Imported Namespaces list, select the check box for the namespace that you wish to add.